# How do I embed music on a webpage and have it play automatically when executed or clicked?

Tags: audio, tags, html4

I'm trying to find a tag/code that allows me to play background music when a webpage is launched or executed, is there any that is compatible with Google Chrome and if there are any, which codes work with chrome?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//w3c//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>My First Web Application</title>
</head>

<body>
<bgsound src="music/sample.mp3">
   <noembed><img src="images/download.jpg" ></noembed>
</bgsound>
<a href="music/fur-elise.mid">Fur Elise</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<bgsound>` tag is Internet Explorer-specific and will thus not work in other browsers such as `FireFox` or `Chrome`. The `<embed>` tag should work in `FireFox` and `Chrome` if you use it correctly. It will use a browser plug-in to play the sound. Below is an example:

```
<embed loop="true" src="music/sample.mp3" hidden="true" type="video/quicktime"></embed>
```

`loop="true"` specifies to play the sound repeatedly.
`src="sample.mp3"` specifies the relative path of the sound file to play. The variety of formats you can play depends on what `type=` you specify.
`hidden="true"` indicates to not show the media player's interface. Hide it if you want the user to not be able to pause, stop, or navigate through the sound.
`type="video/quicktime"` specifies to use a Quicktime component, which means the client must have Quicktime installed. Use application/x-mplayer2 for Windows Media Player or `audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin` for Real Player audio. `Quicktime` plays more formats and is probably what you will want to use.
Alternatively, use `<object>` in a very similar way. An example is below:

```
<object data="music/sample.mp3" type="video/quicktime" width="0" height="0">
    <param name="mp3" value="music/sample.mp3">
    <param name="autostart" value="1">
    <param name="playcount" value="true"> 
</object>
```

The embedding method places a media player in your page. Here's the most basic version of the code:

```
<audio controls="controls"><source src="music/sample.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>
```

If you would prefer not to show the player (and give the user no control), use this code:

```
<audio><source src="music/sample.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>
```